# Why loading dynamically assets fails on Nuxt v3

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, assets, vite, nuxtjs3

I'm experience a weird situation,

I have a "standard" `Nuxt v3` project that comes with vite

**Works**

```html
<img src="~/assets/img/image.png">
<img src="~/assets/video/video.mp4">
```

**Does not work**

```html
<img :src="require('~/assets/img/image.png')">
<img :src="require('~/assets/video/video.mp4')">
```

Note that the image path is the same so it does exist, the error I'm getting is:

> Cannot find module '@/assets/img/image.png' Require stack

[The docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/assets/) don't mention anything that has to be done in order to achieve it

[image]

Is there anything I should do?

Comment: A similar question got asked this morning, here is [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74681067/dynamically-add-an-img-in-nuxt-3#comment131822693_74681067). Also, you're reading which documentation here? Looks like the one for Nuxt2 (with Webpack4). Since you're using Vite, please follow my comment.

Comment: hello @kissu The official docs https://nuxtjs.org/docs/ might be from the nuxt 2 version, do you have the link of the version 3? I don't think I understand your links so I would like to go through it

Comment: Here you have the docs for Nuxt3: https://nuxt.com/

Comment: thanks! but it doesn't mention any of that.. https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/assets I'm trying with: this code `videoUrl.value = new URL(`/src/assets/video/hero-video-double.${props.isIOS ? 'mp4' : 'webm'}`, import.meta.url)` and that string prints out `/src/assets/video/hero-video-double.webm` but `videoUrl`  is `http://localhost:3333/undefined` any thougts?

Comment: Please read my [initial comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74688433/why-loading-dynamically-assets-fails-on-nuxt-v3?noredirect=1#comment131824989_74688433) Everything is written down there.

Comment: yes, I'm trying with option 3 of that SO answer's link, but is not explaining why to use like that and is failing to me and I don't know where to get more info..

Comment: Use the `2022 answer: Vite 2.8.6 + Vue 3.2.31` one.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, although I'm trying to load a video ant that answer is trying to load `().href`

Answer (score 13):

In Vite, the `require` function is not used; instead, you should utilize the `import` statement (Vite is the default module bundler for Nuxt 3).

**Two main issues exist:**

1. After the build, Vite alters the assets directory and file names.
2. Aliases do not convert to absolute paths when used dynamically.

For example, the following won't work:

```html
<img :src="`_nuxt/assets/img/${imageName}`">
```

**It works during development mode, but not after the build**

## Solution 1

I found this method:

```
export const useDynamicImage = (path: string): string =>
    new URL(path, import.meta.url).toString();
```

Add this to your compostables. You can pass your path to this function and retrieve the absolute path. This approach continues to function correctly even after the build.

**use `/src` not `@/`**

## Solution 2

I found this way:

```js
<script>
const glob = import.meta.glob("~/assets/images/how-to-use/*", {
  eager: true,
});

const getImageAbsolutePath = (imageName: string): string => {
  return glob[`/assets/images/how-to-use/${imageName}`]["default"];
};
</script>
```

You can pass your `imageName` (don't forget the extension) to this function and retrieve the absolute path.

This approach continues to function correctly even after the build.

## Solution 3

Import images and use them like this:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
//@ts-ignore
import image1 from "../assets/images/image1.jpg";
//@ts-ignore
import image2 from "../assets/images/image2.jpg";
//@ts-ignore
import image3 from "../assets/images/image3.jpg";

const images = [image1, image2, image3];
</script>
```

## Solution 4

Place your images in the public directory.

learn more: [Nuxt Docs - Public Directory](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/assets/#public-directory)

> The public/ directory content is served at the server root as-is.