# v-list-item prepend avatar not showing

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm iterating my `v-list-item` and trying to use images from my assets folder using `prepend-avatar` prop but seems cant get to display it. I'm using vuetify 3 and nuxt 3.

Here is my `v-list-item`

```
<v-list-item
   link
   v-for="item in navLinks"
   :key="item.index"
   prepend-avatar="item.icon"
   :title="item.title"
   :value="item.value"
   :to="item.path"
>
</v-list-item>
```

The array that I'm iterating over

```
navLinks: [
        {
          icon: "@/assets/images/icons/image1.png",
          title: "Link 1",
          value: "link 1",
          path: "/",
        },
        {
          icon: "@/assets/images/icons/image2.png",
          title: "Link 2",
          value: "link 2",
          path: "",
        },
        {
          icon: "@/assets/images/icons/image3.png",
          title: "Link 3",
          value: "link 3",
          path: "",
        },
        {
          icon: "@/assets/images/icons/image4.png",
          title: "Link 4",
          value: "link 4",
          path: "",
        },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `assets` folder to store the images. I would recommend using the `public` folder if you want to store static files. More information from Nuxt about the `assets` and `public` folders [here](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/assets)

To access the `public` folder in your code, just using the `/`.

I've tested it and it works. See example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-pc7usa?file=app.vue

**Note:** Do not store sensitive files inside the public folder

Comment: thanks for your answer, I found similar issues to mine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74688433/why-loading-dynamically-assets-fails-on-nuxt-v3