# Why does my dynamic image not display in child component using SSR in Nuxt and Quasar?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, server-side-rendering, quasar-framework, nuxt3

I am working on SSR projects (Nuxt, Quasar). When I try to display a dynamic image in a child component, the image is not displayed.

My current code is:

```
function getUrl (img: string)  {
  return require(`@/assets/imgs/sidebar/${img}.png`);
}
```

It shows error message

> Cannot find module '@/assets/imgs/sidebar/side_1.png.png' Require stack: - E:\Work\0503_game777\nuxt-quasar\components\sidebar\SideBarItem.vue

I don't know what is the reason but the image path is correct and also it shows when I use the path directly.

And also I tried like this:

```
function getUrl (img: string)  {
  return `/_nuxt/assets/imgs/sidebar/${img}`;
}
```

It works locally but, when I built it, then it doesn't show the image.

I tried to get dynamic image path with "import" instead of "require()" but is show the promise error. My current code is TypeScript.

Comment: This link might be helpful for you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74688433/why-loading-dynamically-assets-fails-on-nuxt-v3

Answer (score 0):

I've solve the problem by moving the image to public folder.
Thanks

Comment: And which folder was it?